# Why invalidate must be called by UI thread

Tags: java, android

Anyone know why [invalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#invalidate%28%29) must be called by UI thread?

As in Java Swing, the `repaint` function can be called by both non-UI thread and UI thread. `repaint` is performing a very similar task as `invalidate` *(this method causes a call to this component's paint method as soon as possible. Otherwise, this method causes a call to this component's update method as soon as possible.)*.

Comment: Personally I think this question is "underrated". I've also though about this question, and I came up to the point that the reason is synchronization. If you update(redraw) UI only from 1 thread, then there's no reason to do synchronization. Imagine scenario: in thread1 you check textView for equality to some string "text", if succeeded you change the textView to "text" + "1". But meanwhile thread2 could possibly change content to "text2", and you could end up with "text21", which is not what you wanted. So, no need to synchronize. Other meanings?

Comment: Found this while looking for an answer to the titular question (which wasn't answered below), but as a data point - I had a bug where the UI thread would hang, randomly, because we were calling invalidate from a non-UI thread - but the program would otherwise appear to work fine. I'm curious why it worked at all, and why the UI thread hanging was the failure state (rather than the calling thread).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, they are not the same. There's also an [invalidate](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Container.html#invalidate%28%29) method in Swing, and that one does also require the invoker to be invoking it from the EDT/Swing/UI-thread.

Looks like the equivalent to repaint on Android is [postInvalidate](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#postInvalidate%28%29)

Answer (score 0):

When we call `invalidate` from a UiThread it tells the application to redraw the view when the main thread goes idle.So when we call `invalidate` ,it basically schedules the views to be drawn again when all other immediate work is completed.If you want redraw the view in a separate thread other than UiThread then use `postInvalidate()`.